# How do you iterate through an array and store the results in single objects or variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

Using Javascript, how would you go about iterating through an array, then 
storing the results into a single object or variable? I know I could easily write separate functions to accomplish this, but what if I needed to do this within a single function?

This code does what I want, but is obviously repetitive. How would you DRY this code up and return the results in a single variable?

```
var groupIds = ['G8372', 'G895', 'G12030'];

var groupOne = this.state.groups.find(g => g.get('extId') === groupIds[0]);
var groupTwo = this.state.groups.find(g => g.get('extId') === groupIds[1]);
var groupThree = this.state.groups.find(g => g.get('extId') === groupIds[2]);

var groupOneMembers = groupOne.get('members')
  .filter(member => member.get('role') === 'member');
var groupTwoMembers = groupTwo.get('members')
  .filter(member => member.get('role') === 'member');
var groupThreeMembers = groupThree.get('members')
  .filter(member => member.get('role') === 'member');

var totalMembers = groupOneMembers.size + groupTwoMembers.size + groupThreeMembers.size;

return totalMembers;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: If you are wanting to just find the total members, then why split them into separate groups in the first place? Why not just apply the filter on something like `groupAll` or `this.state.groups`?

Comment: This is totally weird code. Why do you define three functions `groupOne`, `groupTwo` and `groupThree`, if they differ only in an index value? The same applies to `groupXXXMembers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
let total = 0;
for (let gid of ['G8372', 'G895', 'G12030']) {
    total +=
        this.state.groups.find(g => g.get('extId') === gid)
        .get('members').filter(member => member.get('role') === 'member')
        .size;
}
return total;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks. The `for` statement handles all of the calculation without having to assign any variables other than 'total'.

Answer (score 0):

```
var groupIds = ['G8372', 'G895', 'G12030'];
return this.state.groups.select(function(group){
  return (groupIds.includes(group.extId) && group.role ==='member' )
}).length
```

not 100% sure on the make up of your data though.